# ffmpeg "ignore_loop 0" seems not work on specific gif

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif

I use code which worked for every gif I used to embed it within a video:

```
ffmpeg -i e:\tt121b+.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i e:\gals\1\gif.gif -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih/10[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[u];[b][u]overlay=(main_w-w)-(main_w*0.1):(main_h-h)-(main_h*0.125):shortest=1" -r 25 -b:v 1500k e:/tt121_logo.mp4
```

It literally adds an animated image to video on specified place and with chosen size. But when I add a gif which has 180 frames it behaves weirdly. After 15 seconds the gif is looped one, then it stops and the whole video stops but program still codes it to the end but with higher speed. Additionally, the ram is used to the maximum after this breakdown.

What's going on there? Should I put some additional parameters? I tried to add `-loop 0`, `-loop 1` in different places and also removed `shortest=1` parameter but its either does nothing or the gif have 1 loop and stops.

**EDIT**

Found the problem. I opened this gif in first found editor and saw that it was not saved as looped infinitely. Saved it in that format and it works. Didn't know the `ffmpeg -loop` parameters don't make it. However, this unlooped gif worked as looped in preview software to add more mess to the topic.

Comment: `-ignore_loop 0` tells ffmpeg to execute the loop count stored in the GIF. Use `-stream_loop -1`  to force indefinite looping of any format.